# how to insert html tags data into database by using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var id=$("#id").val();
      var status=$("#status").val();
      var jtitle=$("#jtitle").val();
     function submitData(){
      var id=$("#id").val();
      var status=$("#status").val();
      var jtitle=$("#jtitle").val();
      var jdesc=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
      alert(jdesc);
$.ajax({
        url: 'JobUpdate.php?status='+status,
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: 'html',
        data: 'status='+status+'&jdesc='+jdesc+'&jid='+id+'&jtitle='+jtitle,
        success:(function(response){
          alert(response);
        })
      });
}
```

I want to send html tags by using textarea and insert into database.Please help to give any an idea.

Comment: what problem you are facing? Please Elaborate.

Comment: sending html tag to table will not be a problem. Are you going to display those details?

Answer (score 0):

All HTML data need convert to base64